# Conflict of windows.h and limits?

Tags: c++, limit

The following code doesn't work in VS2010. What is the reason?

```
#include <limits>
#include <windows.h> // if I remove this line, it is okay.

int main()
{
    std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
    return 0;
}
```

I created a VC empty console project and add a main.cpp as above. It this the reason? May I need to create another kind of project? Thanks.

Thank you for your guys' help. The problem comes from I am using [`vld.h`](http://vld.codeplex.com/) and `limits` together. I do read `vld.h` to try to find the problem by myself. After some testing, I find the problem may be from the `window.h` that `vld.h` includes. Sorry for forgetting to google it. And I personally find stackoverflow is very helpful with your guys kind help for new programmers as me.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but what's with the "not a real question" votes? Do people just feel they have a "close question quota" they need to fill?

Comment: How doesn't it work? What is the error?

Comment: @jalf the original revision of this "question" had absolutely no question at all. It was just this code snippet with the line "It doesn't work. That's strange"

Comment: That and typing "limits windows.h" into google pretty much answers the question. So we have a poor question that doesn't actually state the error and no research on the OPs part. Downvotes and closing generally follow.

Comment: @Rapptz: and yet it gave enough information to solve the problem. True, it didn't have a question mark in it, but really, SO used to be about *helping* people with programming problems. He describes a real issue, gives enough information that people who are familiar with it can answer it, and, well, isn't that good enough that we should *tolerate* it being answered?

Comment: It was pretty clear as for what was being asked. If you don't get the question doesn't mean it is "not real".

Comment: @BrianRoach: Yes... But if you've spent more than a couple of hours on SO, then you ought to know that "you should have googled it" is **never** a valid response here. The goal with SO is effectively to ensure that *if* you google it, you end up here, where you can rely on the answer you get being of a high quality. Telling people to google it is counterproductive and not very helpful

Comment: Well, I didn't VTC seeing as I don't have enough rep to do so anyway. I was just explaining the probable rationale.

Comment: @jalf First statement if you hover your mouse over that downvote button: *The question doesn't show any research effort*

Comment: @BrianRoach: "research effort" is not the same as "googling it". You can research the issue in many ways, for example as the OP did, by experimenting with the code, with removing one header or the other, and (correctly) determining that the problem is due to a conflict between the `<limits>` and `<windows.h>` headers.

Comment: Yeah ... we'll just have to disagree on that one. If you can't be bothered to type two words into a search engine ...

Comment: @BrianRoach: well, I'm sorry, but you are disagreeing with direct quotes from Jeff and Joel, the f'ing founders of the site. So we can disagree if you like, but on this matter, I happen to be right, and you are not. Tough luck. :) It boils down to the fact that some people actually intend for this site to be *useful*. It is not useful if you tell people "go google it and rely on an arbitrary and unvetted answer whose quality you have no way of gauging", instead of posting an answer here where it can be judged and evaluated by your peers

Comment: @BrianRoach do you really hate your fellow programmers so much? Why do you prefer that people google for answers? How are people supposed to know whether the answers they find there are *correct*? And what purpose does SO serve, if people should prefer Google instead? I think it's saddening to hear someone genuinely believe that this site should be less useful. Your votes *do* count as much as mine, but if you want to change the rules on SO, I suggest you take it up on Meta.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, Sure, you might not know that answers here are *correct*, but you do have multiple tools (votes, reputation, comments, etc.) to suggest which ones are probably *better*.  Which puts this site well above most other resources you find elsewhere.  Of course, answers here that do reference TFM are better answers.  Closing questions as some kind of punishment for perceived lack of effort is ridiculous.  I'm glad my software bosses don't dock my pay because I finish my work early and easily, as opposed to doing everything the hard(er) way, just to show that I'm straining.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a known problem caused by an unfortunate `max` macro defined in `windows.h` (actually, `windef.h` included by `windows.h` to be more precise). Defining `NOMINMAX` before including `windows.h` should solve the problem. For example:

```
#define NOMINMAX
#include <windows.h>
```

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes the `#define NOMINMAX` doesn't work (I've see such examples), then you can always `#undef MIN` & `#undef MAX`.

Also, as you are using VS2010 it's typically a good idea to put such preprocessor workarounds for windows in the `stdafx.h` and not repeat them all the time.